# Need help parsing through this HTML using BeautifulSoup and Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have the following HTML I would like to parse using BeautifulSoup:

```
<tr class="TrGameOdd">
  <td align="center">
    <a href="Schedule.aspx?WT=0&amp;lg=778&amp;id=,1583114">
      <img border="0" src="/core/engine/App_Themes/Global/images/plus.gif">
    </a>
  </td>
  <td align="left">Oct 20</td>
  <td>777</td>
  <td align="left" colspan="2">Cupcakes</td>
  <td align="right">7+3
    <input type="checkbox" value="0_1583114_-3440" name="text_">
  </td>
  <td align="right">a199
    <input type="checkbox" value="2_1583114_-199.5_-110" name="text_">
  </td>
</tr>
```

There are a whole bunch of lines like this, but I only need specifics out of it. For example, I want to parse `777, Cupcakes, 7+3, -3440, a199` out of all of this. How would I go about doing that? I'd like it to print side by side and I would have a few of these lines I want to parse, so when it prints it should be like this:

```
777 Cupcakes 7+3 -3440
X X X X
X X X X
etc
```

Comment: Format your code properly in order to avoid scrolling

Comment: Sorry about the formatting, new here - I've tried
    `code` html.find_all('tr')
    print tr.find_all('td') `code`

Comment: find_all()? are you inventing method names?

Comment: Because he obviously is a beginner and with down voting you're just demotivating him

Comment: beginner is not an excuse for trying *nothing* at all

Comment: This is the reason why I wrote him a quick example and pointed him to a BeautifulSoup website

Comment: Nah - Its not that at all. Its very confusing since I dont have a programming background. I can manipulate around, but when i read the tutorial, it isnt specific or clear to the point where it can help you parse through tables or 'tricks' to get what you need.

Comment: check the updated answer, if you can't figure it out, then you're on your own

Comment: I've tried this but get a mess of stuff
`code` stuff = html.find_all ('tr')
for tr in stuff:
print tr.find_all('td')

Im not sure what I can do specifically get those pieces I am looking for or how to break them apart from all the other code.

Comment: @Goranek - thanks for that, what does [1] [2] [3] represent

Comment: you have lots of <td>s in your code, [0] is first td, [1] is second td and ...

Comment: @user1833746, This was probably upvoted because the hat dash is motivating people to participate on SO by upvoting questions and answers.

Comment: @user1833746: "find_all()? are you inventing method names?"  `find_all` is the default name for that method in bs4, and the one used in [the docs](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).  See [here](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#method-names) for the list of method name changes.

Answer (score 3):

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
trs = soup.find("tr",{"class":"TrGameOdd"})

for tr in trs:
   tds = tr.findAll("td")

   print tds[1].string # Oct 20
   print tds[2].string # 777
   print tds[3].string # Cupcakes
   ...
```

You need to continue yourself
http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Comment: Im not a dev, so a little hand holding and I can get it done. The doc is so confusing

Comment: @user1833746 Why are you trolling? Im asking for help and posted what I have so far. If you're not interested in helping, then don't. Someone might have time to guide me and I'll take that instead.